# MvcSiteMap display sub menu items on mouse over

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

How to display sub menu items on mouse over of main menu item in mvcsitemap

Comment: Just realized that menu drop down thing is more to do with css. Need not be handled in code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by specifying menu css to the li items in MenuHelperModel.cshtml as suggested in

[Ed Spencer's Blog](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/)